# How can I set the current tick count of a goog.Timer?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

I am tinkering with `goog.Timer` and reading its API: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_Timer.html

Is there a way to set the current time or tick for the timer? For instance, can I set the current time into the timer to be 5000 milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`goog.Timer` is an abstraction above [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) that repeatedly dispatches a `goog.Timer.TICK` event at a set interval. The interval may be specified using the first constructor parameter or the method `setInterval()`.

Here is an example that increments a tick counter once every 5 seconds.

```js
var tickCount = 0;

/**
 * Tick callback.
 */
var tickCounter = function() {
  tickCount++;
};

var timer = new goog.Timer(5000);
timer.start();
goog.events.listen(timer, goog.Timer.TICK, tickCounter);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that and also stored the number of ticks in another wrapper class.